# Google Sign-In API with PHP Looping

Tags: php, api, loops, authentication, google-signin

I have been using a Google Sign-in API for our system. It has been working fine the past year until suddenly, it just started looping to the sign-in page endlessly. This has just started happening now and it started happening once I used a different account to log-in to the system.

I have already tried messing with the code and I have also tried fixing the credentials in the Google APIs page but no luck. I have traced the code and found that it wasn't returning any code to be stored in the $code variable shown below.

```php
<?php require ("../css/vendor/autoload.php");
session_start();
require_once('../mysql_connect.php');

//Initialization
$g_client = new Google_Client();
$g_client->setClientId("260506751278-f15240qthdtd15vduqiap98a1oi8qk3o.apps.googleusercontent.com");
$g_client->setClientSecret("JOeshw3N8gjnRdB39xcakw0o");
$g_client->setRedirectUri("http://localhost/ccs/pages/login.php");
$g_client->setScopes("email");
$g_client->setPrompt("consent");
//Create the Authorization url

$auth_url = $g_client->createAuthUrl();
header("Location: $auth_url");
//echo "<a href='$auth_url'>Login Through Google </a>";

// authorization  code
$code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : NULL;

// Get access token
if(isset($code)) {
    try {
        $token = $g_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
        $g_client->setAccessToken($token);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    try {
        $pay_load = $g_client->verifyIdToken();
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else{
    $pay_load = null;
}

   $email=$pay_load["email"];
   $fn=$pay_load["name"];
   $ln=$pay_load['family_name'];

    $qemail="select * from faculty_account where faculty_id='{$email}'";
    echo $qemail;
    $resemail=mysqli_query($dbc,$qemail);

    if(isset($pay_load)){

         if (mysqli_num_rows($resemail)!=0)
         {
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($resemail,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $faculty_id=$row['faculty_id'];
            $if_registered = $row['if_registered'];
            $_SESSION['faculty_id'] = $faculty_id;

            if($if_registered == 1){

                $_SESSION['fn'] = $fn;
                $_SESSION['ln'] = $ln;

                header("Location: index.php");

            }

            else{

                header("Location: register.php");

            }

         }
         else{
             echo $qemail;
            header("Location: unauthorized.php");
         }


    }?>
```

I expect it to log me into the system which it used to do, but now it just loops.

EDIT: I would also like to point out that clearing absolutely everything from my browers work only ONCE. I would be able to log-in one time then never again, even if I reproduced the steps. I think it would also be important to note that the system is being run on an XAMPP server.

EDIT 2: Alright, I found that it does redirect to a URL with a gettable code variable "http://localhost/ccs/pages/login.php?code=4%2FgQF4oDmkaZrs1n47uKmHAS1r1Xrvhd-8RvDXC67kAne6jmyStvlOM2mbiXn3u_ZyKshE1SgS83P_mnJQPeloRsY&scope=email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&session_state=36e43354d2853a201602abdf62d2fa2172c51177..e703&prompt=consent#". I used Internet Explorer and funnily enough, It was so slow that I could get the RedirectURI with its variables. Now I completely have no idea what's going on. I'm assuming it's an error on Google's behalf or something is wrong with the tokens.

Comment: And which exact line causes that loop? What have you tried to spot and debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase the line where it gets the authorization code. It seemed that it always set the payload to null. The way I checked it is putting different header codes under each conditional which would allow me to identify which conditions are being satisfied. It seemed to always go to the else statement setting the payload to null.

Comment: @NicoHaase It turns out that line does not cause the loop. It does get a code, but it probably has something to do with the tokens or the authorization code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out I was correct in the second edit. There was something wrong with the token. It turns out that it was throwing an error with the token, concerned with my system time. It was apparently caused due to difference in time zones. I solved this by changing the 'leeway' property of the jwtclass to 200 instead of 1. This will pose some security issues. However, should your project not require much security, this is a quick fix.